# Encrypting the vector of 0 and 1s

Tags: encryption-symmetric, encryption-asymmetric

I am about to create a vector of size n, with zero and ones. I want to encrypt all the elements of the vector, but I am wondering if encryption of the elements reveals information about the zero and ones. Is there any specific cryptosystem at which when I encrypt the zero and 1s they are not distinguishable in their ciphertext form?

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: C, C++ or python. Does this matter or only the type of cryptosystem matter?

Comment: All vectors are 0s and ones. In computers, everything is binary. What do you mean?

Comment: I am sending a vector of size n which the elements of the vector are zero and one. I want to send the Enc(0) and Enc(1) over the network, but I am looking for a cryptosystem that when I am encrypting the zeros and ones, the pattern zeros and ones be indistinguishable.

Comment: You're not asking a simple question here.  Encryption is a very complex subject.  Can you be more specific as to what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to encrypt a vector of length n, with 0s and only one element 1 at a specific index of the vector(i). I want to encrypt the 0s and the 1, so no one can see the plaintext and also I want to be sure if the cryptosystem works like the encryption of the zeros and encryption of 1 does not reveal any information about the elements so no one knows there is 1 at index i and 0 at other places. My concern is more about the indistinguishability of the ciphertexts.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer. If we are encrypting the elements of the vector using encryption algorithms like RSA/padding, we can get different outputs for the same plaintext. So, we can encrypt the elements of the vector with these kinds of algorithms and get different results, so the ciphertext is indistinguishable each time.